# preventDefault is recurring into child li's when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, html, preventdefault

I have the following code and jsFiddle link below. In my head my code should work, it finds the right li tag and disables the default action, the problem is it is recurring it into the child elements aswell when it shouldn't. Can you shed some light please?

http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/6HAvV/

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class=""><a href="home.htm">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_parent"><a href="our-projects.htm">Our Projects</a>
        <ul class="nav_child">
            <li class=""><a href="the-palms-at-corozal.htm">The Palms At Corozal</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="the-lakes-at-consejo.htm">The Lakes At Consejo</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_parent"><a href="about-us.htm">About Us</a>
        <ul class="nav_child">
            <li class=""><a href="who-we-are.htm">Who We Are</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="other-projects.htm">Other Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="partners.htm">Partners</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_parent"><a href="about-belize.htm">About Belize</a>
        <ul class="nav_child">
            <li class=""><a href="general-info.htm">General Info</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="investing-in-belize.htm">Investing In Belize</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="useful-links.htm">Useful Links</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="news.htm">News Articles</a>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="contact-us.htm">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul#nav li:eq(1)').addClass('removeLink');
    $('.removeLink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're binding to the `li` element, and since the children are within the `li`, they also trigger the `click` event.

Try updating and prevent the click on the `a` element only:

```
$('.removeLink > a').click();
```

Here's an [**updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6HAvV/1/).

Comment: I was so close! haha. Thanks very much. Will accept this answer when SO lets me :)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted :)